# Getting XSS detected in my project

Tags: xss

XSS is getting detected in my code.

```
String ref = new CellReference(rownum, columnIndex).formatAsString();
_out.write(ref);
```

it detects at this line.

I have been using Appscan. Tried this:

```
String ref = ESAPI.encoder()
    .encodeForHTMLAttribute(new CellReference(rownum, columnIndex)
    .formatAsString());
_out.write(ref);`
```

However, it did not work. Please help me to remedy this XSS finding.

Comment: For very specific programming questions, should really ask on SO. Vote for a move...

Comment: Are you using ref anywhere outside HTML attributes? If so, you may need to call different encode methods based on where ref is used.

Comment: @MrWerbenjagermanjensen  No i am not using ref anywhere outside HTML attributes. It is just being used here .
Do you have any idea to solve this

Comment: @MrWerbenjagermanjensen can you suggest which other encoding methods I should try ??

Comment: If you're using ref only in HTML attributes, then I'm not sure what the problem is. The method you are currently using should make ref safe to use in HTML attributes. If you were using ref somewhere else like in Javascript, you would want to use another method like encodeForJavascript.

Answer (score 0):

Appscan source does not mark up the ESAPI call as a validation mechanism out of box.  When you rescan this code that ESAPI call should appear in the trace diagram.  You can then mark the ESAPI call as a validator against XSS in the trace diagram.  Once that API is marked, any subsequence scans will remove this finding.